# How to use Service in Composable Component which created by MainActivity

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-service

I am creating a Service to connect and read data from Bluetooth.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

  companion object {
    lateinit var serialService: SerialService
  }

  var dataListener: DataListener = DataListener()

  override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val intent = Intent(this, SerialService::class.java)
    startService(intent)
    bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
  }


  private val mServiceConnection: ServiceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
    override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {

    }

    override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
      Timber.tag("Timber").d("onServiceConnected")
      serialService = (service as SerialService.SerialBinder).getService()
      serialService.attach(dataListener)
    }
```

With this approach I can call serialService from child Composable:

```
MainActivity.serialService.connect(device)
```

But I am not sure this is good method to implement and manage Service.